# Is .profile or .bashrc backed up anywhere automatically?

Tags: terminal, backup

There are hidden files that are fairly important if you use terminal a lot at ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc, etc. Are these files backed up anywhere by default? sometimes I append to environment variables to `.profile` via command line, e.g. `echo 'export foo=bar' >> ~.profile` and realized that I could be in big trouble if I accidentally left out one of the `>` characters.

Comment: Nothing at all is backed automatically - What is your normal backup? Given this we can say how the .bashrc etc files should be backed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no special handling of `.profile`, `.bashrc` or any other config file within OS X. So unless you are running a regular backup (e.g. using Time Machine), these files will be lost if you type `>` instead of `>>`.

Some of-the-top-of-the-head ideas to overcome this

- run a regular backup (there are probably files on your computer which are more important than `.profile` so you should be doing this anyway)
- change habits and use the text editor of your choice to update shell profiles
- create a shell function to do the append operation, e.g. something like this (untested)

  ```
  add_to_profile() {
      echo >> ~/.profile
      echo '# ' Added on $(date) >> ~/.profile
      echo $* >> ~/.profile
  }
  ```

  and use it like `add_to_profile 'export foo=bar'`.
- use Hazel (or Folder Actions) to backup `.profile` and `.bashrc` automatically after each change
- put those files under version control (either locally or on Github)